# submeter parte do formulário - jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

estou tentando postar uma parte do formulário mas já tentei de algumas formas e ainda continuo com problemas.

Segue um print da tela 
[clique pra ver a imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYzig.jpg)

```
    <h:form id="QuestaoCreateForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="display">
        <p:panelGrid columns="4" rendered="#{questaoController.selected != null}"  layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank" style="border:0px none; background-color:transparent;">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoLabel_enunciado}" for="enunciado" />
            <p:inputTextarea id="enunciado" rows="6" cols="33" value="#{questaoController.selected.enunciado}" title="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoTitle_enunciado}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoRequiredMessage_enunciado}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoLabel_orientacao}" for="orientacao" />
            <p:inputTextarea id="orientacao" rows="6" cols="33" value="#{questaoController.selected.orientacao}" title="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoTitle_orientacao}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoLabel_assunto}" for="assunto" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="assunto" value="#{questaoController.selected.assunto}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditQuestaoRequiredMessage_assunto}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}"  noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{assuntoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                               var="assuntoItem"
                               itemValue="#{assuntoItem}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateQuestaoLabel_tipoQuestao}" for="tipoQuestao" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoQuestao" value="#{questaoController.selected.tipoQuestao}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditQuestaoRequiredMessage_tipoQuestao}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}"  noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{tipoQuestaoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                               var="tipoQuestaoItem"
                               itemValue="#{tipoQuestaoItem}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:panel header="Associar itens à Questão" >
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
                <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateItemQuestaoLabel_textoItem}" for="textoItem" style="color: red" />
                <p:inputText id="textoItem" value="#{questaoController.itemQuestao.textoItem}" title="#{bundle.CreateItemQuestaoTitle_textoItem}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Nota:" for="nota"  />
                <p:inputNumber id="nota" value="#{questaoController.itemQuestao.nota}" title="Nota" decimalPlaces="2" />

            </p:panelGrid>


            <p:commandButton id="btn_add" value="Adicionar" update="itens_da_questao,:growl @parent" action="#{questaoController.reinit}" >
                <p:collector value="#{questaoController.itemQuestao}" addTo="#{questaoController.selected.itemQuestaoList}" unique="false"/>
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton id="btn_reset" value="Limpar" type="reset"/>
        </p:panel>


        <p:panel header="Itens da Questão" id="itens_da_questao" >


            <p:dataTable style="width:200px;" value="#{questaoController.selected.itemQuestaoList}" var="itemQuestao" id="booksTable" rendered="#{not empty questaoController.selected.itemQuestaoList}"  >

                <p:column headerText="Item Adicionado">
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemQuestao.textoItem}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Action">
                    <p:commandLink value="Remove" update=":QuestaoCreateForm:itens_da_questao" process=":QuestaoCreateForm:itens_da_questao">
                        <p:collector value="#{itemQuestao}" removeFrom="#{questaoController.selected.itemQuestaoList}" unique="false"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{questaoController.create}" action="/jsf/questao/List.xhtml"  value="#{bundle.Save}"  update="display,:growl" 
                         process=":QuestaoCreateForm:enunciado, :QuestaoCreateForm:orientacao, :QuestaoCreateForm:assunto, :QuestaoCreateForm:tipoQuestao"
                         partialSubmit="true"
                         />
        <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}" action="/jsf/questao/List.xhtml" immediate="true"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

O ideal seria trabalhar com 2 forms ? Forms aninhados ?
já tentei várias formas na configuracao do botao..

Comment: Seria interessante [edit] sua resposta com mais informações, nem todo mundo vai poder abrir a imagem para conseguir te ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não pode aninhar forms no JSF.
O botão save deverá salvar o panelGrid e os itens ja escolhidos. Para isso adicione um id ao panelGrid e no botão save coloque ex.:`process="@this id_panel_grid_exemplo"` o @this serve para processar o próprio botão.

Você tambmém deve adicionar um id ao panel que engloba os dois primeiros campos e os dois botoes: limpar e adicionar. O botão de adicionar deverá processar este id. ex.: `process="id_exemplo"`

No segundo passo processe apenas o botão, já que a lista já estará no bean. SEe process deverá ficar assim